# get specific page of .odt document using java (odftoolkit)

Tags: java, odt, odftoolkit

```java
OdfDocument odfDocument = OdfDocument.loadDocument(in);
 
int pages =  odfDocument.getOfficeMetadata().getDocumentStatistic().getPageCount();
```

I am getting the total pages, but can't find a solution to get specific page of `.odt` document. Can you propose an approach for this?
I am trying to find a solution using `odftoolkit`. Read the documentation but did not find any helper method that gives a specific page of `.odt` document.

Comment: For those looking for answer to this questions, I did not find any specific method in the documentation which gives you specific page of odt file using pure java open source solution. Since I needed a free solution, it did not work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in OdfToolkit .odt implementation there is only one page. Sure the page count could be 10 or whatever the "real" page counter may look like in your program e.g. LibreOffice. But OdfToolkit sees all text as one page.
That means you can get the number of pages but you need to access the text of all pages not over there pages.